# Extract vmlinux from Android (Samsung) zImage

Tags: android, kernel

I'm trying to extract the ELF kernel image from Samsung S9 zImage.

All the information I could find is outdated and didn't work for me.

Here's what I tried:

```
$ binwalk ./zImage

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
109488        0x1ABB0         SHA256 hash constants, little endian
13107320      0xC80078        Linux kernel version "4.9.59 (fuzz@fuzzy) (gcc version 4.9.x 20150123 (prerelease) (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Dec 2 21:23:06 AEDT 2019"
13135872      0xC87000        ELF, 64-bit LSB shared object, version 1 (SYSV)
13155800      0xC8BDD8        gzip compressed data, maximum compression, from Unix, NULL date (1970-01-01 00:00:00)
13468623      0xCD83CF        Private key in DER format (PKCS header length: 4, sequence length: 2345
13522696      0xCE5708        LZO compressed data
13524096      0xCE5C80        CRC32 polynomial table, little endian
13956632      0xD4F618        CRC32 polynomial table, little endian
15232073      0xE86C49        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos_booster_init"
15232097      0xE86C61        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos_booster_request_pm_qos"
15232129      0xE86C81        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos_booster_start"
15232153      0xE86C99        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos_booster_stop"
16398151      0xFA3747        Boot section Start 0x43434342 End 0x72
16398155      0xFA374B        Boot section Start 0x72 End 0x0
16564344      0xFCC078        YAFFS filesystem
16783528      0x10018A8       SHA256 hash constants, little endian
16921164      0x102324C       Unix path: /home/euleyskiy/Perforce/SRK_EULEYSKIY_SEC_DEV3/DEV/Solution/SecurityDev3/SURC/FIVE/DEV/trusted_app/arch/tbase/stack_protector.c
16924308      0x1023E94       Unix path: /home/vm-user/Workspace/MCD_MSL_DEV_IMAKARCHUK_Ubuntu/DEV/Solution/SecurityDev/SubTG/Multibuild/DEV/libgpapi_crypto/src/storage.
16924740      0x1024044       Unix path: /home/vm-user/Workspace/MCD_MSL_DEV_IMAKARCHUK_Ubuntu/DEV/Solution/SecurityDev/SubTG/Multibuild/DEV/libgpapi_crypto/src/crypto_r
16926392      0x10246B8       Unix path: /home/euleyskiy/Perforce/SRK_EULEYSKIY_SEC_DEV3/DEV/Solution/SecurityDev/SubTG/Multibuild/DEV/multibuild/source/gp-api/prop/src/
16926828      0x102486C       Unix path: /home/euleyskiy/Perforce/SRK_EULEYSKIY_SEC_DEV3/DEV/Solution/SecurityDev/SubTG/Multibuild/DEV/multibuild/source/gp-api/persisten
16969177      0x102EDD9       Unix path: /../../crypto/cipher/cipher.c
16970721      0x102F3E1       Unix path: /../../crypto/bn/add.c
16974228      0x1030194       Base64 standard index table
17937463      0x111B437       mcrypt 2.2 encrypted data, mode: CBC, keymode: 8bit
17944943      0x111D16F       Unix path: /arch/arm64/include/asm/mmu_context.h
17955348      0x111FA14       Unix path: /arch/arm64/include/asm/pgtable.h
17959554      0x1120A82       Unix path: /include/trace/events/sched.h
18001357      0x112ADCD       Unix path: /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
18013859      0x112DEA3       Unix path: /arch/arm64/include/asm/pgalloc.h
18167662      0x115376E       xz compressed data
...
```

According to various sources the image is the LZOP part (LZO at offset 13522696):

```
$ dd if=./zImage of=out.lzop bs=13522696 skip=1
$ file out.lzop
out.lzop: lzop compressed data - version 0.000, os: MS-DOS
$ lzop -d out.lzop
lzop: out.lzop: header corrupted
```